# Rails JSON conversion error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I'm getting a strange error when trying to convert my object to json for an API connection. The following details my experience.

If I call

```
JSON.generate(self)
```

the output is

```
{"validation_context":null,"errors":{},"params":{"number":"123","name":"test"}}
```

I only need the params in my json object and when I call

```
JSON.generate(self.params) # or the next line
JSON.generate(@params) #params has been set on the object as an accessor
```

I get

```
undefined method `merge' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x1043f1a38>
```

For some reason `params` is not considered a Hash. It serializes ok when I'm getting the parent object but fails otherwise. How can I serialize just the params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I found a relatively simple solution.

Rather than

```
JSON.generate(object_to_serialize)
```

Using

```
object_to_serialize.to_json
```

Will work as intended.